# How to use JS to filter div elements of a definite class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The essence of the problem: there is a list of divs with the `username-card` class. First subtask: check if the value entered by the user exists in the array of `title` attributes of all divs in the class. If it doesn't exist, return an error. If it exists, then the second subtask is solved: hide all divs that do not match the value entered by the user.

The condition for the absence of a username in the array is triggered. But the cycle of enumerating elements and hiding unnecessary cards are not. Separately, both functions work. I can't figure out what's wrong.

My `JS` code:

```js
function showSearchedUserCard() {
  const username = document.getElementById("inputSearchUserCards").value
  const divList = document.querySelectorAll('.username-card');
  const titles = []
  divList.forEach(el => {
    titles.push(el.title);
  })
  if (titles.includes(username)) {
    hideUserCards(username)
  } else {
    document.getElementById("inputSearchUserCards").value = 'User does not exist';
    document.getElementById("inputSearchUserCards").style.color = 'red';
  }
}

function hideUserCards(username) {
  const cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('username-card'));

  for (const card of cards) {
    if (card.title === username) {
      card.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      card.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.username-card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <input type="search" class="form-control" id="inputSearchUserCards" placeholder="Enter username" list="UserName">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-9">
  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="showSearchedUserCard()"> 
           <strong>Filter</strong>
     </button>
</div>

<!-- Example data -->
<div class="card-body px-0 py-0">
  <div class="username-card" title="Bob">Bob</div>
  <div class="username-card" title="Joe">Joe</div>
  <div class="username-card" title="Mary">Mary</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A sample of the rendered HTML `username-card` s might be useful

Comment: Your JS code works fine for me.

Comment: what is your expectation if the search value is `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a single event listener like this. Set the display of ALL `.username-card` elements and then selectively change the display of any matching elements. That same mechanism is used to modify the boolean variable within the event listener to indicate success/failure

```js
document.querySelector('button.btn-success').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  // find reference to the input element and ensure the error class is removed
  let uname=document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="search"]');
      uname.classList.remove('error');
      
  // find all username-card div elements & ensure all are visible
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('div.username-card');
      col.forEach(n=>n.style.display='block');
  
  let bool=false;
  
  // if the user entered a value, determine if the entered value exists in one of the DIV titles
  // modify global boolean value
  if( uname.value!='' ){
    col.forEach(n=>{
        if( n.title.toLowerCase()!==uname.value.toLowerCase() )n.style.display='none';
        else bool=true;
    })
  }
  // some sort of error message
  console.log(`Username: ${uname.value} exists: ${bool}`);
  
  // highlight that the username does not exist
  if( !bool )uname.classList.add('error')
})
```

```css
.username-card:after{
  content:attr(title)
}
.error{
  color:red;
  box-shadow:0 0 1rem rgba(255,0,0,0.75)
}
input{margin:1rem;padding:1rem;}

.username-card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-12">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name='search' placeholder="Enter username" list="UserName">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-9">
  <button class="btn btn-success"><strong>Filter</strong></button>
</div>




<div class="card-body px-0 py-0">
  <div class="username-card" title="roger"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="sheila"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="billy"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="dan"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="roger"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="carrie"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="becky"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="Bob"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="Joe"></div>
  <div class="username-card" title="Mary"></div>
</div>
```